# How do I position images left and right in wordpress post

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to be able to insert images into a Wordpress post and have my layout position them left and right. The problem I'm encountering is that the css pseudo selector for `nth-child(even)` and `nth-child(odd)` starts counting from the parent, making the `<P>` tag the parent for my images.

```
img{
    position: relative;
    max-width: 480px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

div img:nth-child(odd){
    position: relative;
    left: -240px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: -224px;
}

div img:nth-child(even){
    position: relative;
    right: -240px;
    float: right;
    margin-left: -224px;
}

<div class="content">
    <div class="col-12">
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <p><img src="image.jpg" alt="image">Quisque porttitor risus dapibus augue interdum tincidunt. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur malesuada eleifend egestas. Proin vitae euismod lectus. Proin pretium est dolor. Donec finibus lorem nunc, vel rhoncus velit feugiat eu. Maecenas vel dui elit. Fusce feugiat massa quis magna euismod aliquam. Vivamus eget malesuada eros, a placerat nibh. Vestibulum faucibus tortor ac velit pharetra accumsan. Duis id neque lorem. Donec in varius quam, a pulvinar lorem. Suspendisse fringilla aliquam augue sit amet molestie. <img src="image2.jpg" alt="image2"></p>
        <h2>heading</h2>
        <p>Quisque porttitor risus dapibus augue interdum tincidunt. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur malesuada eleifend egestas. Proin vitae euismod lectus. Proin pretium est dolor. Donec finibus lorem nunc, vel rhoncus velit feugiat eu. Maecenas vel dui elit. Fusce feugiat massa quis magna euismod aliquam. Vivamus eget malesuada eros, a placerat nibh. Vestibulum faucibus tortor ac velit pharetra accumsan. Duis id neque lorem. Donec in varius quam, a pulvinar lorem. Suspendisse fringilla aliquam augue sit amet molestie. </p>
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Quisque porttitor risus dapibus augue interdum tincidunt. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur malesuada eleifend egestas. Proin vitae euismod lectus. Proin pretium est dolor. Donec finibus lorem nunc, vel rhoncus velit feugiat eu. Maecenas vel dui elit. Fusce feugiat massa quis magna euismod aliquam. Vivamus eget malesuada eros, a placerat nibh. Vestibulum faucibus tortor ac velit pharetra accumsan. Duis id neque lorem. Donec in varius quam, a pulvinar lorem. Suspendisse fringilla aliquam augue sit amet molestie.<img src="image3" alt="image3"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to I make it so that inserted images are evenly distributed left and right inside page?

*edit: http://jsfiddle.net/udxzs5jj/

Comment: Can you provide us with a fiddle?

Comment: Did I explain well enough what I wanted to achieve?

Comment: Are you trying to position the writing blocks or the grey block because I've got the black writing on a white background to stretch across the width of the page..

Comment: I am trying to position the images in a way that the images indent the text while also expending outside the text. However in this order: 1left, 2right 3left etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There ought to be a CSS solution to this and I'm sure if I scratch my head long enough I might even come up with it.

Anyone who does come up with it has a better solution that the one below...

**CSS**

```
img.left {
    position: relative;
    left: -240px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: -224px;
}

img.right {
    position: relative;
    right: -240px;
    float: right;
    margin-left: -224px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

var i;

for (i = 0; i < images.length; i = i +2) {
images[i].classList.add('right');
}

for (i = 1; i < images.length; i = i +2) {
images[i].classList.add('left');
}
```